# Why I am getting 400 bad request for SOAP XML in JMeter?

Tags: performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I have a **SOAP XML request**, which **works fine in Load Runner**. Whereas in **JMeter**, getting **400 Bad request**. Can anyone look into it and share what is causing this error?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[HTTP Status 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) means "Bad Request", it indicates that your request is syntactically incorrect.

- Double check that your request body is valid XML using i.e. online [XML lint tool](https://xmllint.com/)
- You might need to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send correct [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) and [SOAPAction](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528) headers

Going forward given your request works in LoadRunner you can easily use JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) to record it.

If you configure LoadRunner to use JMeter as the proxy

[image]

you will be able to replay LoadRunner script and JMeter will capture the requests and create relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers.

[image]

More information:

- [How to Convert LoadRunner Tests to JMeter](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-convert-loadrunner-tests-to-jmeter)
- [Convert LoadRunner to Open-Source JMeter in Minutes](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/loadrunner-jmeter-conversion)

Comment: Yes.. I did the same. I used JMeter, recorded load runner reply, identified difference and fixed the issue. thanks any how..

Answer (score 0):

\n in line number 11 and ending double quotes in line number 9 are the reason for 400 bad request. Once removed both, fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving a `400 Bad Request` error, which originates from the target test application.  There is something unexpected with the way that you are forming your request that the server does not recognize.

JMeter has multiple tools built in that can assist in debugging such a problem.  [This article](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2021/09/troubleshoot-your-jmeter-load-tests/) does a good job in summarizing them.  You can add a "[View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)" element which will output both the request and the response detail.  Alternatively you can [enable debug logging](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) to see additional low-level information, or specify custom outputs.

Another technique you can do is intercept the request as formed by JMeter, and use a third-party tool such as [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) to see if your result is any different.  Using  a tool such as this will enable you to change request headers which may also be contributing the problem.